# Amplify angular build error

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I am using Amplify angular in an Angular project. having error when building.

here the error :

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/overlays.d.ts(9,82): error
>   TS2344: Type 'keyof B' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
>   Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>       Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Package.json

```
{
    "name": "******",
    "version": "0.0.2",
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "config": {
        "host": "*********",
        "cloudfront": "**********"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "[ -f src/aws-exports.js ] && mv src/aws-exports.js src/aws-exports.ts || ng serve; ng serve",
        "build": "npm run commit && [ -f src/aws-exports.js ] && mv src/aws-exports.js src/aws-exports.ts || ng build --configuration=production; ng build --configuration=production",
        "commit": "git add -A && git commit -m 'an other commit' && git push",
        "deploy": "aws s3 rm s3://$npm_package_config_host --recursive && aws s3 sync ./dist/browser s3://$npm_package_config_host --cache-control='max-age=2628000, public' && aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $npm_package_config_cloudfront --paths '/*'",
        "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
        "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
        "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --configuration=production && ng run ******:server",
        "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
        "@nguniversal/common": "^6.0.0",
        "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^6.0.0",
        "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^2.0.0",
        "aws-amplify": "^1.0.4",
        "aws-amplify-angular": "^1.0.2",
        "aws-sdk": "2.282.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
        "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "^2.5.7",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "ngx-quill": "^3.3.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
        "quill": "^1.3.6",
        "sha1": "^1.1.1",
        "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
        "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.1",
        "@angular/cli": "^6.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.5",
        "@types/node": "^10.5.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.4.2",
        "cpy-cli": "^2.0.0",
        "express": "^4.16.3",
        "http-server": "^0.11.1",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
        "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~2.9.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
    }
}
```

angular.json configuration

```
  "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": true,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": true,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }]
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a [bug with Ionic package](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/pull/14553), at build even if you don't use ionic.it is fixed by the ionic team, but not yet updated by the amplify team.
so just waiting for new versions,

i can confirm, and according to the github bug issuer that there is a workaround waiting the update :

> "compilerOptions": { "keyofStringsOnly": true }

here the [github issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1326)